# How to position background image horizontally left and vertically center?

Tags: html, css

I would like to position a CSS background image. All sample I found centers both vertically and horizontally. I would like align *left* but vertically *center* The docs samples like:

```
background-position: top;
background-position: bottom;
background-position: left;
background-position: right;
background-position: center;
background-position: 25% 75%;
background-position: 0px 0px, center;
```

also does not clear how to separate the horizontal and vertical alignment.

Iterestingly [this doc](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) and [this other one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) (and many more) does not even mentioning the word 'horizontal' and 'vertical' or 'x' / 'y'....

What am I missing?

Comment: `background-position: 20px center;`, here first param is X axis and the other one is for Y

Comment: Remember to search (in google, stackoverflow, etc) before ask. That's a basic concept of css `background`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: I've searched. It turns out from the question. You also mentioned stackoverflow where I've also searched.. Please note: this is not a duplicate. Or could you point to a stackoverflow question what answers my question even implicitly?

Comment: I don't reffer to a duplicate. I reffer to a generic search of background position values. In 5 seconds I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position (read entire article). As I said, that's a very basic question in CSS, easy to find in tons of billions of webs. This is only a note, not an answer neither.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I was a bit slower, I've found it 10 sec. That is the page I am originally quoting in my original question (exactly). If you read carefully the that page you it is only mentions vertical and horizontal _once_ in relation of _percents_ . So based on that page the answer is not  only not obvious, it is not specified.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. You are attached the link to `background-image`, I attach the link to `background-position`.  If you read it carefully you can view all possible values and **a lot of examples** with `background-position: left center` and what it means...

Comment: 1) I was talking about the _code_ sample in my question, what is about background-position and _exactly_ the samples on the link you are referring. There is _no_ answer on that page to my question. 2) About your reasoning: "...a lot of examples...": Of _course_ googling to the _answer_ it will list links with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `background-position: <<horizontal>> <<vertical>>`

```
background-position: left center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these:

```
background-size: cover; 
background-position: left center;
```